# callback not working in AWS lambda invoking

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, callback

```js
    const connectToDB = async uri => {
   if (cachedDb) {
      return Promise.resolve(cachedDb);
   }
   return MongoClient.connect(config[STAGE].dbUrls[uri], { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(db => {
      cachedDb = db;
      return cachedDb;
   });
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   console.log("[Find All] [event] : ", event);
   context.callbackWaitForEmptyEventLoop = false;
   connectToDB('MONGODB_URI_FIND').then(database => {
      let db = database.db(config[STAGE].dbUrls.DB_NAME);
      console.log("db connection  ", db);
      fetchDataFromDb(db, event, callback);

   });
};

const fetchDataFromDb = (db, event, callback) => {
   const { table, query } = event;
   const options = { ...query.options };
   delete query.options;
   const { sortFields, limit, skip } = options || {};
   db.collection(table).find(query, options).sort(sortFields || {}).limit(limit || 999).skip(skip || 0).toArray((error, result) => {
      console.log("Fetched data[] : ", { error, result });
      if (error)
         callback(null, { body: error });
      else
         callback(null, { body: result });
   });
};
```

In the above code, the callback(null,{}) function is not executing, Code is working when I am using return or context.done() instead of callback(). please help me to execute callback.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to use

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
```

instead

```
context.callbackWaitForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```